# How do I post result in the box on html page via express.js?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a difficult time trying to make html and node express work together. 
I want the result
 `{ "date": April 15, 2017", "unix": 1492214400   }` 
 to be posted inside the box ( enclosed in p ) on html page instead of to be opened in new window. 
Here is what I have tried so far. Can you pinpoint what is wrong?
I appreciate your help.

```
enter code here
```

```js
$("#submitDate").submit(function(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  var convertInput = (!$("#inputDate").val()) ? $("#inputDate").attr("placeholder") : $("#inputDate").val()
  var tar = window.open(window.location.href + convertInput, "_blank");
  tar.focus();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are accessing the Node endpoint by using window.open, which will open in a new window.  You should be sending the request using one of JavaScript's asynchronous request APIs. Generally these would be [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the newer [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). As it seems you're already using jQuery or some other JS library, they may also have their own methods for sending HTTP requests.

For instance, something along these lines would probably do the trick.

```js
let submit = async function(data) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    // data object containing data payload
    const data = await response.json();
    $(".borderBox").innerText = JSON.stringify(data); // or whatever data you need from the data object
}
```

In adapting your case, I would recommend making a few changes so that your request handling function looks more inline with this:

```
$("#submitDate").submit(async function(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  var convertInput = (!$("#inputDate").val()) ? $("#inputDate").attr("placeholder") : $("#inputDate").val()
  const response = await fetch(window.location.href + convertInput);
  const data = await response.json();
  document.getElementsByClassName('borderBox')[0].innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where should I put it in? What is the data object? I don't follow what you posted .Can you clarify more?  I would like returnObject {"date":naturalTime.toDateString(), "unix":parseTime.toString()} to be displayed in the borderBox.

Comment: It should be utilized in the handler of the response to your request. If your response is sent correctly as JSON, it will unwrap the response data into the data object, which you can then utilize.  You may want your Node server to send it as JSON specifically using `res.json(returnObject);` See the edit in the answer for a more applicable example.

Comment: I put your edit on client.js in glitch.com and it is not getting through. I don't see anything in the box. It says "Parsing error: Cannot use keyword "await" outside an sync function". Any suggestion?

Comment: Ah, yes, the function declaration will have to be defined as async. See the edit in the code sample.

Comment: Yes, second edit ( $("#submitDate").submit(async function(i) {  )   is fixed now but first edit (  let submit = function(data) {   ) is not working. It says same parsing error ( cannot use await outside an sync function). Where should i put the first edit?  in client.js or server.js?

Comment: The first one is just an example of how the process could be utilized separate from your particular example. You shouldn't need to utilize it, though I'll edit it to use async properly here. You should only need the code from the second snippet.